# How can I Embed a Google maps map dynamically in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, maps

I’m trying to dynamically show a map on the product page wit latitude and longitude coordinates or just city name. I cant get the map to show

This is what I have so far, this is the html:

```
          <div>
            <iframe
              allowfullscreen
              height="450"
              loading="lazy"
              referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
              [src]="getMapUrl()"
              style="border:0"
              width="600"
            ></iframe>
          </div>
```

this is the typescript:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.productId = Number(params.get('productId'));
      this.boatName = params.get('name') as string;
      console.log(this.productId + ": productId")
      console.log(this.boatName + ": boatName")
      // console.log("Coords: " + this.boat.latitude + ", " + this.boat.latitude);
      document.title = `${this.boatName} || Boat and Share`;

      // call the product service to fetch the product details
      this.boatsService.getProductById(this.productId).subscribe(boat => {
        this.boat = boat;

        console.log("The boat: " + this.boat.name + ', ' + this.boat.boatType)
        his.getMapUrl()
      });
    });
  }

getMapUrl(): string {
    const latitude = this.boat.latitude;
    const longitude = this.boat.longitude;
    return `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=${environment.apiMapsKey}&q=${this.boat.latitude},${this.boat.longitude}`;
  }
```

All help is highly appreciated!

EDIT:

The errors I get in the console in the browser

```
ERROR Error: NG0904: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see https://g.co/ng/security#xss)
    at ɵɵsanitizeResourceUrl (core.mjs:7391:11)
    at elementPropertyInternal (core.mjs:10839:37)
    at Module.ɵɵproperty (core.mjs:13584:9)
    at ProductInfoComponent_div_0_Template (product-info.component.html:153:15)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:10481:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10366:13)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:11381:17)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10390:9)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11427:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:10157:9)
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors, what's in your console?

Comment: Angular provides a GoogleMaps component in their component development kit.  Maybe that will help (instead of using an iframe manually)

Comment: @JakeSmith I tried doing that but the only thing I got were errors so I thought maybe it would be better to embed :/

Comment: @NilsKähler I updated the question with the errors I get in the console!

Comment: Try wrapping your return value in getMapUrl in `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl` -> `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(\`https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=${environment.apiMapsKey}&q=${this.boat.latitude},${this.boat.longitude}\`)` This tells angular that you want to bypass security and use the unsafe value.

Comment: @NilsKähler You're a legend! Could you turn this comment in an answer so I can accept it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because Angular deems the use of the returned data from `getMapUrl` to be vulnerable to a [XSS attack](https://angular.io/guide/security#trusting-safe-values).

Try wrapping your return value in `getMapUrl` in sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl()

```
getMapUrl(): string {
    const latitude = this.boat.latitude;
    const longitude = this.boat.longitude;
    return sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=${environment.apiMapsKey}&q=${this.boat.latitude},${this.boat.longitude}`);
}
```

This tells Angular that you want to bypass security and use the unsafe value.